# getting 404 error trying to upgrade outdated 19.10 to 20.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 19.10

404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
Err:22 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release

my file is using

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
```

but when I enter the link there is no eoan release 
right now im trying to upgrade outdated ubuntu
how should I change the

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *groovy gorilla* [20.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.10 is 22 October (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: As stated before, *The repositories for 19.10 haven't moved yet for the main archive. The move occurs after EOL, but each mirror can take that to mean the next day, or months from now (whenever convenient) so it's on users to do it using automated tools BEFORE release reaches EOL, or match their mirror/repository manually if they miss the EOL deadline.*

Comment: Also as stated before,*
Is your system fully-upgraded? Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades as after a release goes EOL, it's repositories are moved (which can occur quickly, mirrors can drop an EOL release). This change is manual as it's expected users will release-upgrade prior to the EOL occurring (notice was given if you were watching). Refer the release notes for 20.04 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) in the "Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10 section" for upgrade instructions. They were intended to be used before 19.10 reached EOL*

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to the latest version of ubuntu forcefully, type:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```